# Is it possible to include text in the extracted menus in `helm-imenu`?

Tags: helm, imenu

I try to use `helm-imenu` to construct a custom menu of headings, where the menu
items are slightly different to what is shown in the headings.

Say I have an ordinary org file with some headings

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2
```

Upon calling to `helm-imenu` I will get

```
Heading 1
Heading 2
```

Now, using previous example, how can I achieve a menu with the following
contents ?

```
+ Heading 1
+ Heading 2
```

That’s to say, is it possible to alter `helm-imenu` (`imenu`) default behaviour, so that
it makes possible to add some text (plus sign, in this example) to the
extracted headings, without modifying the heading itself ?

Comment: The question needs clarification -- I've read it three times, but am still confused as to the call of the question.

Comment: @lawlist Better now ?

Comment: The question is now squarely in the `helm-imenu` category, so it's time for me to bow-out and let people experienced with `helm` take over from here.  Thank you for the clarification.